# android/java how to encrypt a boolean variable with email address

Tags: android, encryption

I would like to store a boolean variable in private shared preference. I would like to add some security, at least, it will not be simply for a rooted device to simply modify the boolean variable. I am thinking to use email address to encrypt the boolean. I read some stackoverflow that I can to convert to char[]( what is that??) and then xor(??) with a key? I dont really have knowledge in encryption theory, can anyone provide some sample code to "encrypt a boolean variable with email address"? thanks

Comment: Since it's a boolean, you could make it false if it's true, or true if it's false.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypt a boolean? How funny!!
OK, you can perfor such a hide in MANY different ways.

You could use a number (say 700) or a string (say "ni hao") and then check it against a number (if the number you save is 9009 then it's true, else it's false - in the example, 700 is not 9009, so you'd get false) or a string (if the string you save is "ni hao" then it's true, else it's false - in the example, "ni hao" is "ni hao", so you'd get true), just to name two common and easy ways.

Your fantasy is your limit.
Even if I still must see the sense of hiding a boolean, which is a single bit.

**I read some stackoverflow that I can to convert to char[]( what is that??) and then xor(??) with a key? I dont really have knowledge in encryption theory**... well, NOT FOR A SINGLE BIT!!

**can anyone provide some sample code to "encrypt a boolean variable with email address"?**. the "ni hao" example will do. just replace "ni hao" with an email (an evidently fake one, like "example@no_address.com") and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1: User jBCrypt

Download latest jBCrypt from [here](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/)

Sample code of the encryptor:

```
public class BooleanEncryptor {
public String encryptBoolean(String password, boolean value){
    String pass = password + (value?"1":"0");
    return BCrypt.hashpw(pass, BCrypt.gensalt());
}
public Boolean decryptBoolean(String password, String encrypted){
    if(BCrypt.checkpw(password, password+"1")){
        return true;
    }
    if(BCrypt.checkpw(password, password+"0")){
        return false;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

You can then do something like

```
    String encryptedBoolean = BooleanEncryptor.encrypt("email@example.com", true);
```

and store the result in you SharedPreferences.

The trouble with that is where to store that password or email securely. So we have option 2 ...

## Option 2: For Android 4.3 and above

Extend this example [SecretKeyWrapper](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/Vault/src/com/example/android/vault/SecretKeyWrapper.java)  to extends it and create an encryptor as shown bellow

```
public class SampleEncryptor extends SecretKeyWrapper{
private static final SecureRandom RANDOM = new SecureRandom();

private SharedPreferences pref;
private SecretKey secretKey;
private byte[] encryptedKey;

public SampleEncryptor(Context context)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    super(context, "myalias");
    this.pref = context.getSharedPreferences("mySecretKeyStore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String base64key = pref.getString("key", null);
    if(base64key==null){
        this.secretKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
        this.encryptedKey = this.wrap(this.secretKey);
        pref.edit().putString("key", Base64.encodeToString(encryptedKey, Base64.DEFAULT)).commit();
    }else{
        this.encryptedKey = Base64.decode(base64key, Base64.DEFAULT);
        this.secretKey = this.unwrap(this.encryptedKey);
    }
}

public byte[] encrypt(byte[] data) throws GeneralSecurityException{     
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    return  cipher.doFinal(data);
}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] data) throws GeneralSecurityException{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    return  cipher.doFinal(data);
}

public String encryptBoolean(boolean value) throws GeneralSecurityException{
    BigInteger i = new BigInteger(128, RANDOM);
    if(value){
        i = i.setBit(0);
    }else{
        i = i.clearBit(0);
    }
    byte[] encrypted =  encrypt(i.toByteArray());

    return Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);
}

public Boolean decryptBoolean(String encrypted) throws GeneralSecurityException{
    byte[] data = Base64.decode(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);     
    BigInteger i = new BigInteger(decrypt(data));
    return i.testBit(0);
}
```

}

Then you can do something like

```
    encryptor = new SampleEncryptor(myActivity);
    encryptor.encryptBoolean(false);
```